# Is pow(x, 2.0) fast as x * x in GLSL?

Tags: optimization, glsl, pow

In my programming class we had to program a `pow(float, float)` function in Java and that made me realize how hard it is for your computer to do such calculation. However, `pow(float, int)` is very easy as you only have to multiply your first argument by itself in a loop. For that reason, I always made my own `pow2(float)` and `pow(float, int)` functions when programming video games.

However in GLSL, I'm hesitant about making functions unless they are really needed since I have to copy paste my functions in all shaders. I think the power function problem becomes even more important in shaders though.

Is `pow(float, float)` smart enough to do just `x * x` when `y = 2` and so on for other integers? Is it worth making my own `pow2(float)` or `pow(float, int)` function? Or is there already functions to do that? I'm asking because I've been doing the `x * x` multiplication manually and it's making my code less clear to read.

Comment: Since the GLSL code is compiled by the driver, it is probably driver dependent.

Comment: if any of those were faster, compilers would transform one into the other as optimization.

Comment: @Rabbid76 So is it a good idea to make my own `pow2()` function just in case?

Comment: @Winter If I want to calculate `pow(x, 2)`, then I always write `x*x`.

Comment: What if `i = (a + b + c)`? Will you make a local variable just for that? Or will you do `(a + b + c) * (a + b + c)` that greatly degrades code quality?

Comment: Also when you say "copy and paste your code into each shader", I believe it is quite popular to make a set of functions that can be included. Like have something like

$replace_me_with_functions

and then before compiling replace it with the functions you want.

Comment: Given how critical the `pow` function is in lighting models, I think any vendor would make sure that their shader compiler explicitly handles an integer exponent. That's purely specular speculation though:) It's not going to be any *faster* than `x * x`, regardless of how binary exponentiation is performed.